# MDX Query aggregate combining crossjoin expression with non-crossjoin/comma-separated expression

Tags: mdx

I have an issue while retrieving on columns with `crossjoin(someMeasure1,someMeasure2) , someMeasure3`. 
Details:

```
WITH MEMBER [Date].[Custom] AS 
  'Aggregate({[Date].&[20220101]:[Date].&[20220810]})' 
MEMBER [Measures].[Total YTD] AS 
  '([Date].[Test1], [Measures].[Customer])' 
SELECT 
  crossjoin(
     {[Measures].[Customer Form], [Measures].[Customer]}, 
     [Date].[Monthly Key]
  ), 
  [Measures].[Total YTD] on 0, 
  nonempty(
    {[Hier Top].[Hier1].[city].members}
  ) on 1 
FROM 
  [WAREHOUSE]
```

It gives output:
[image]

How do combine `someMeasure3` (ie `[Measures].[Total YTD]`) with the other crossjoined members? (I believe it's similar to SQL's aggregate functions, eg `sum()`/`count()`/`max()`/etc, with `group by` clause)

Best Wishes

Answer (score 0):

Just realise there's `Union()` function there, or operator `+`. I can specify the second member of the tuple as `Year` key. Solution is

```
WITH MEMBER [Date].[Custom] AS 
  'Aggregate({[Date].&[20220101]:[Date].&[20220810]})' 
MEMBER [Measures].[Total YTD] AS 
  '([Date].[Test1], [Measures].[Customer])' 
SELECT 
  crossjoin(
     {[Measures].[Customer Form], [Measures].[Customer]}, 
     [Date].[Monthly Key]
  )
  +
  ([Measures].[Total YTD], [Date].[Yearly Key]) on 0, 
  
  nonempty(
    {[Hier Top].[Hier1].[city].members}
  ) on 1 
FROM 
  [WAREHOUSE]
```

Note that I am using op `()` not `{}` to specify the member dimensionality manually for `[Measures].[Total YTD], [Date].[Monthly Key]`

All good